# Не удалось показать /media/root/B6064A43064A04B9

Tags: linux

После того как для обычного пользователя в Kali я установил оболочку mate, вышла такая проблема. Не могу через файловый менеджер войти на логические диски. Разве что с терминала только могу.

Если войти в систему от root, где gnome, то там всё нормально открывается.

Comment: Kali не предназначена для обычного использования простыми пользователями. Установите какой-нибудь минт или убунту. Там все будет просто. Но если очень сильно нужно - настраивайте права в udev для монтирования дисков.

Comment: Зачем вообще в Kali делать подобные модификации? Данная ОС предназначена для проведения тестов на безопасность.